# htaccess point any subdomain to folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can i point any subdomains to folder?
For example, point domain  `sub.domain.com/test` to `domain.com/subdomains/sub/test`.
And how to leave the `sub.domain.com/test` url unchanged?

I've need to work not only **sub** subdomain. **Any** of subdomains.

Comment: Question is not clear at all. What is a sub subdomain? How are they setup in Apache? What is the DocumentRoot for main domain and sub domain?